# Proxy DHCP via dnsmasq: Grub welcomes me, but then gets stuck

Tags: networking, dhcp, efi, grub2, pxe

I am attempting to EFI PXE boot GRUB2 using a Proxy DHCP server... It worked just fine with this configuration, which simply replaced the DHCP server:

```
interface=enp3s0
dhcp-range=192.168.1.10,192.168.1.90,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.1.1
pxe-prompt="Going to network boot", 4
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/ftpd
dhcp-boot=grubnetx64.efi
```

The client boots up just fine.
However, that is not what I want. I want IP allocations to still be handled by the routers DHCP server. So I changed it to this:

```
interface=enp3s0

dhcp-range=192.168.1.1,proxy

enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/ftpd

pxe-prompt="Going to network boot", 4
pxe-service=x86-64_EFI,"Network boot",grubnetx64.efi
dhcp-boot=grubnetx64.efi
```

Both Intel UNDI (or whatever this thing is called) and iPXE are able to start GRUB2, however it doesn't get any further than the "Welcome to GRUB!" banner, after which is just freezes and all network activity stops. After a long while, I end up in the grub shell (not the emergeny shell) without any error messages. The config wasn't loaded at all.

Interestingly, iPXE doesn't show me any IP addresses when running `dhcp` or `ifstat`, as if it hasn't gotten an IP address, but it is able to automatically fetch the `grubnetx64.efi` file off the server.

Wireshark reveals that the client has fully downloaded the `grubnetx64.efi` file, but then all communication stops, including DHCP.

This is a network dump of the bootup, up until the point where the boot file starts downloading.

```
No. Time         Source        Destination     Protocol Length Info
19  25.842147691 0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 DHCP     389    DHCP Discover - Transaction ID 0x2ac0b917
20  25.842958215 192.168.1.124 255.255.255.255 DHCP     342    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x2ac0b917
21  25.844230209 192.168.1.1   255.255.255.255 DHCP     342    DHCP Offer    - Transaction ID 0x2ac0b917
24  29.480009427 0.0.0.0       255.255.255.255 DHCP     401    DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x2ac0b917
25  29.483931744 192.168.1.1   255.255.255.255 DHCP     342    DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x2ac0b917
28  29.484919255 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   DHCP     389    proxyDHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0xfe4617c6
29  29.485937159 192.168.1.124 192.168.1.137   DHCP     342    proxyDHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0xfe4617c6
33  30.485321160 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     86     Read Request, File: grubnetx64.efi, Transfer type: octet, tsize=0, blksize=1468
34  30.486167149 192.168.1.124 192.168.1.137   TFTP     71     Option Acknowledgement, blksize=1468, tsize=3864000
35  30.486335275 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     72     Error Code, Code: Option negotiation failed, Message: User aborted the transfer
36  30.511880616 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     78     Read Request, File: grubnetx64.efi, Transfer type: octet, blksize=1468
37  30.512618251 192.168.1.124 192.168.1.137   TFTP     57     Option Acknowledgement, blksize=1468
38  30.512763523 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     60     Acknowledgement, Block: 0
39  30.513057030 192.168.1.124 192.168.1.137   TFTP     1514   Data Packet, Block: 1
40  30.513471667 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     60     Acknowledgement, Block: 1
41  30.513903970 192.168.1.124 192.168.1.137   TFTP     1514   Data Packet, Block: 2
42  30.514401757 192.168.1.137 192.168.1.124   TFTP     60     Acknowledgement, Block: 2
```

Do you have any idea why this may be happening? I am absolutely puzzled. And quite new to the internals of DHCP and PXE.

Thanks in advance
Tuxifan

Comment: On which hardware are you having issues, have you tried multiple? I would not rule out a bios/firmware/rom bug on that behavior, (NIC ROM UNDI stack bug)

Comment: On any. Even on iPXE.